# Compilation error: variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, android, if-statement, scope

All- I have looked at lots of questions similar to this but can't seem to fix my problem. My problem is that a variable that is declared outside of an if statement but is initialized inside of one is not being recognized by a variable in the same scope it was defined in. Here is my code:

```
  String lastP1Boa; //Declared here

if (ownersBoa == message) {
    Spinner houseBoa = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.houseBoa);
    String housesBoa = houseBoa.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Integer lastIntHouseBoa = Integer.parseInt(housesBoa.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));

    Spinner hotelBoa = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hotelBoa);
    String hotelsBoa = hotelBoa.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Integer lastIntHotelBoa = Integer.parseInt(hotelsBoa.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));


    int intLastP1Boa = lastIntHotelBoa * 1500 + lastIntHouseBoa * 100;
    lastP1Boa = String.valueOf(intLastP1Boa);  } //Initialized here



String p1Total = lastP1Boa; //Error saying that lastP1Boa needs it be initialized
```

Thank you all for your time and hopefully I have made myself clear!

Comment: Your title and problem description are incorrect. The variable is recognized all right, but the compiler tells you it mightn't have heen initialized, which is true. All compilation errors are not alike. You do have to read the message.

Comment: My bad. Sorry that I was misleading with the title but I am relativity new to android and didn't know exactly what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that the compiler is reporting is that there's a chance that `if (ownersBoa == message)` will evaluate to `false` and `lastP1Boa` won't be initialized.  Set it equal to `null` (or some more appropriate default value) where you declare it.

```
String lastP1Boa = null; //Declared here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the first line to `String lastP1Boa = null;`, it should fix your compilation error, though you should make sure that you handle the case where that variable is `null`.

Comment: OK I will make sure to catch if the case is null. Thanks a lot for your help.